# Preview of website - error - when clicking "Like" on my website

Tags: facebook, web, preview

I have added a Facebook Like-Button to my website, which works perfectly. It shows the perfect link to my website on the wall of the persons who click it.
There's only one problem and I can't seem to solve it in any way.
The link also includes a preview of my website, but instead of a complete preview or a preview of my header it shows a picture of one of the link-buttons of my website!
The script itself doesn't contain anything to change or set a preview picture and changing names of pictures, links and header doesn't solve it either. No matter what I do, it still keeps on showing the button...

What can I do bout it?
I've contacted my serverhost but they don't know it either?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the image that shows on Facebook with the following og tag in the head of your page:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/image.jpg" />
```

Facebook requires some more [open graph tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/). (Formerly known as meta tags.)
You have to make sure the facebook linter correctly interprets your page. Use the Facebook [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to check and fix all issues.

Answer (score 0):

try to refresh facebook catch by submitting link [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) . If you still have problem , you can provide custom images by with open facebook graph . [Refer](http://ogp.me/)